# Implementing interfaces with List<T> property

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following problem:

```
public interface IControlSingleContainer
{
   ControlCollection Content { get; set; }
}

public interface IControlCollectionContainer
{
    // I need to obtain a List of objects that implement IControlSingleContainer interface
    List<IControlSingleContainer> Items { get; set; }
}

public class TabItem : IControlSingleContainer
{
    public ControlCollection Content { get; set; }
}

public class TabbedContainer : IControlCollectionContainer
{
    public List<TabItem> Items { get; set; }  <- ERROR!
}
```

This code expect a `List<IControlSingleContainer>` in the property `TabbedContainer.Items` but I try to create classes with `Items` property that contains objects that implement `IControlSingleContainer`.

EDITED: Basically, the compilation error is the following:
`'Cosmo.UI.Controls.TabbedContainer' does not implement interface member 'Cosmo.UI.Controls.IControlCollectionContainer.Items'. 'Cosmo.UI.Controls.TabbedContainer.Items' can not implement' Cosmo.UI.Controls.IControlCollectionContainer.Items' because it has the kind of matching return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List <Cosmo.UI.Controls. IControlSingleContainer>'`.

I explored a solution with generic interfaces but without any results...

Comment: If you came across an error, and you posted this question looking for help fixing that error.... but then didn't even bother to say what the error actually was, then you have failed.

Comment: What is there error message? I'm betting it's an object reference error because you haven't instantiated the list. Try instantiating the list in the class' constructor

Comment: Hi JK, my english is not the best... sorry! I try to explain the error better: When you compile the code I get an error in the Items property of TabbedContainer class, as it expects a list List <IControlSingleContainer>. I really hope that this list is for classes that implement the interface IControlSingleContainer. I can not find how to get this. I hope it is clear my problem ... :)

Comment: Thanks CD Smith. I simplified the code to expose only the problem with declaration of types. The error was produced by compiler, not in runtime:

'Cosmo.UI.Controls.TabbedContainer' no implementa el miembro de interfaz 'Cosmo.UI.Controls.IControlCollectionContainer.Items'. 'Cosmo.UI.Controls.TabbedContainer.Items' no puede implementar 'Cosmo.UI.Controls.IControlCollectionContainer.Items' porque no tiene el tipo de valor devuelto coincidente de 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Cosmo.UI.Controls.IControlSingleContainer>'.

Sorry for language... I have Visual Studio spanish version! :)

Comment: @JK. This is such a classic "stackoverflow police" comment from you. I wouldn't say I like the toxicity on stack overflow and it's one of the reasons people would rather ask their dumb questions on some language model now rather than on a platform with commenters lurking around with nothing better to do than correct everyone.

I think it was a very well-asked question, I easily found this the second I ran into the problem, the top result on Google. Well done GerardLlort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do here but you can't coerce a `List<interface>` into a `List<concrete>`. However, you can make your interface generic and add a constraint like this:

```
public interface IControlCollectionContainer<T> where T : IControlSingleContainer
{
    List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now your class definition becomes this:

```
public class TabbedContainer : IControlCollectionContainer<TabItem>
{
    public List<TabItem> Items { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: Thank's DavidG, this is exactly the solution that I've been looking for! Thank's to all! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're close,

```
 public class TabbedContainer : IControlCollectionContainer
    {
        public TabbedContainer()
        {
            Items = new List<IControlSingleContainer>();
            var t = new TabItem();
            Items.Add(t);
        }

        public List<IControlSingleContainer> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This solution and have evaluated (and certainly works well), but there is no way to create the Items property for a specific object type (that implements the interface IControlSingleContainer)?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons [explicit interface implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) exist depending on your use-case.

In your situation, you want your `Items` to be `TabItem` when working with that `TabbedContainer` directly. However, the interface requires `Items` to be a specific interface.

The trick is to declare `TabbedContainer.Items` and also `IControlCollectionContainer` at the same time, but reusing your `TabItem` class behind the scenes.

```
public class TabbedContainer : IControlCollectionContainer
{
    public List<TabItem> Items { get; set; } 

    List<IControlSingleContainer> IControlCollectionContainer.Items 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return // Your actual tab items 
        }

        set 
        { 
             Items = //Whatever you need to do make sure you have actual
                     // TabItem objects
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to update the sample above to actually handle setting/getting of interface's version of the items, but the main idea is to reuse your `TabItem` collection so they are always in sync.

What this actually does is when you are working with `TabbedContainer` and call `Items`, you will get a list of `TabItem`, but when working with your instance as an `IControlCollectionContainer`, your `Items` will return you the `IControlCollectionContainer.Items` instead.

Do note though that this can become quite a complex venture depending on how you are passing/modifying the instance of the container. It can be tricky to try and get these to sync if you are constantly modifying the items through `TabbedContainer` and `IControlCollectionContainer` declarations. Doing explicit implementations can sometimes help you take a step back and re-evaluate exactly what it is your end goal is and what types you declare on your properties.

For instance, if you aren't actually adding items to your interface's list, then why even use `List`? It could be better as an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thank's TyCobb... tomorrow I will explore this solution... now here are 1 am and I'm very tired! :) Thank's!

Comment: @GerardLlort No problem. It is just another option. There's always a million ways to do things and this one really depends on your use-case. Good luck.